# Using node clone to copy content and delete parent content?

Tags: datetime, nodes

I want to use node clone to copy my old content and at the same time delete the parent content

for example i have a content called Item 1

I want to clone Item 1 want and then delete the original Item 1.
its because drupal views has only the sort by :creation date and I do not want my users to alter the publication date by themselves